# Can't find the files that fill up my Rasbian SD Card

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

df -h gives me the following

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           15G   14G  457M  97% /
/dev/root        15G   14G  457M  97% /
devtmpfs        211M     0  211M   0% /dev
tmpfs            44M  204K   44M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            88M     0   88M   0% /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p1   56M   19M   38M  34% /boot
tmpfs            88M     0   88M   0% /tmp
```

---

while sudo du -hsx * | sort -rh in root directory gives me this

```
du: cannot access `proc/2331/task/2331/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/2331/task/2331/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/2331/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `proc/2331/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
1.4G    usr
239M    var
53M     lib
37M     opt
19M     boot
7.3M    home
6.7M    sbin
5.9M    bin
4.4M    etc
216K    run
20K     media
16K     root
16K     lost+found
4.0K    srv
4.0K    selinux
4.0K    mnt
0       tmp
0       sys
0       proc
0       dev
```

To me this doesn't add up, where are the 14GB in use?

It's a Raspberry Pi Model B with pure Raspbian and only one little python-tool installed (pyLoad), nothing else really.

Comment: If you suspect that to used space is wrong, you should probably run a fsck on root fs. You can force a fsck on reboot with this command : `shutdown -rF now`

Comment: I did that but that didn't really change anything.

Comment: Maybe an open-then-delete file ? see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34140/tell-fs-to-free-space-from-deleted-files-now

Comment: Did you expand your filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `du` command incorrectly, which also explains why you are getting those error messages about `/proc`. Presumably you want to see what is in the root filesystem but nothing mounted under it, so you should say `du -shx /`. The * would have missed any directories in / starting with a period.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ncdu instead of du, it provides a nice interactive terminal UI. It should be in the repository as "ncdu" (`apt-get install ncdu` in apt systems).

Default behavior is to scan the current directory and sort by size. You can tell it to scan a different directory such as `/` with `sudo ncdu /`.
You can use the arrow keys to navigate the displayed file tree. left arrow moves to previous directory, up and down select a listed directory or file, and the right arrow moves to the selected file if it is a directory.

`$`[`man ncdu`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ncdu)